# jQuery UI datepicker IE problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I checked related posts but none of these answered my question. So this is the code i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/datepicker.js"></script>
```

Inside the datepicker.js i have the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("#id_picker").datepicker();
});
```

I also tried to put `document.ready()` around it, but that didn't help neither. The Datepicker is showing I and can use some key controls but I can't **click** on a date so it would appear into my textbox where I open the datepicker with an `onclick`. So I can't select another date, it just doesn't select the date and because of that the dialog stays open until I click out of it.

Any help please? In Firefox, Chrome, Iceaweasl it's working perfectly.

UPDATE****

Apparently this had to do something with IE itself, i tried on many other IE's on different computers where i didn't have this problem. I couldn't trackdown what exactly could be the issue but for me this case can be closed.

Regards,
T

Comment: You should be getting an error in the lower right of the status bar, what does it say?

Comment: that's the problem i don't see any error, i just can't see anythong wrong .... when it was not showing i could understand, but the datepicker is showing, but it's not picking dates hmm

Comment: What is the technology domain are you working? If it is a ASP.Net, then try to make EnableCLientScript false for validation control.

Answer (score 1):

If you run IE on windows server 2003 or 2008, please refer the page [Can Windows' enhanced security break jQueryUI's datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869935/can-windows-enhanced-security-break-jqueryuis-datepicker)

Answer (score -2):

You are probably loading jQuery from the local file system. Try loading from a web location, such as:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: nothing to do with it, elsethe datepicker wouldn't be visible. I tried it anyway what you told but didn't work out. anyway thxs