# onclick javascript and IE Enhanced Security Configuration

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I've got a html part which is added to the DOM at runtime using javascript.
The anchor tag has a onclick event, but it won't fire in IE when IE Enhanced Security Configuration is enabled.

I've tried various IE settings, and also added the site to local intranet with security level low. I just can't tweak the setting to allow the onclick event to fire.

```
<a class="ui-btn ui-btn-active" onclick="javascript:View.SubmitForm()" href="#"> Update </a>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Unless you have VBScript as the first script on the page, you do not need `javascript:` label

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869935/can-windows-enhanced-security-break-jqueryuis-datepicker has a good link