# Kendo Ui DatePicker Cannot Select Date in IE

Tags: datepicker, internet-explorer-9, kendo-ui, ie8-compatibility-mode

Has anyone had problems with Kendo DatePicker in IE9 Compatibility Mode? I am not able to select a date from the calendar except for the current date at the bottom. I found this post, [jQuery UI datepicker IE problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700233/jquery-ui-datepicker-ie-problem), but it did not offer any clues to the problem. This post, http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/date-time-pickers/datepicker-use-ie9-compatibility-mode-ie7-or-ie8-day-not-selected.aspx, also addresses the issue, but the issue still remains. I am currently running Kendo UI Web 2013.1.319 Open Source. Per usual everything is working exactly as expected in Firefox, Chrome, and other modern browsers. Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: DOes the problem exist on the standard version of IE - without changing the compatibility mode?

Comment: If I force the browser to use the meta IE=edge or do not use compatibility mode, everything works as it should. I am running into the problem of users who are browsing with older IE versions after IE 6 but before IE 9. Side note, we do not develop for IE 6 anymore.

Comment: i have the same problem. my company is using IE 7 and IE 7 is not letting the user select a date. It's showing UnSelectable = On in the IE developer toolbar. visit this link for more information  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654817/kendo-ui-datepicker-does-not-let-the-user-select-a-date

Comment: please find the answer to your question at this location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654817/kendo-ui-datepicker-does-not-let-the-user-select-a-date