# Kendo UI DatePicker does not let the user select a date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-7, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo DatePicker with MVC 3 (VB.NET, Razor syntax) in IE 7. When i click on the datepicker it does not let me select the date. By default, today's date is selected. If i run the same code on Google chrome, it works fine. Also i investigated this issue using IE developer toolbar for IE 7, and it's showing that "Unselectable" for the datepicker is set to "On". I have no idea how can i switch it off. I can browse the months or years in the datepicker but can't actually select a date. i can also manually enter the date in the datepicker textbox. any help will be really appreciated please.

This is a sample of the code i am writing

```
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("ExtMailDatePicker").Value(DateTime.Now)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Day)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens when the version of kendo framework installed and the version of jquery installed don't match. for example

using Q2 SP1 2012 assembly of kendo ui, and using JavaScript files from just Q2 2012 (1.7.1) may cause this issue. after making sure i have the correct files, it works.

Comment: Hi Can you suggest an solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380955/kendo-ui-datepicker-not-working-in-safari-browser